# Prove that if W is a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space V, then dim(W) ≤ dim(V).

Tags: linear-algebra

### My attempt at a solution:

*Proof*

Given a vector space $V$, let $S={v_1,...,v_n}$ be a basis for $V$. Consequently $\dim(V)=n$.
Now given $W$, a subspace of $V$, it will be shown that $\dim(W)\le \dim V$

First, consider the case where $W=${0}.
Then $dim(W)=0 \le\ n$,

Subsequently, consider the case for $W=V$. Then it follows that $dim(W)=dim(V)=n$.

Finally, consider the case where $W \subset V$ and without loss of generality assume $v_n \notin W$.
Let $T={v_1,...,v_k}$ where $k\lt n$ be a basis for the subspace W. Now, since *S* is a basis for V, for every $v_i \in S$,  $c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n=0$ has only the trivial solution, thus none of the vectors in S can be expressed as linear combinations of the other vectors in S. It follows that the set *T* is not a basis for V as $v_n$ cannot be generated from *T*. The $dim(W)$ is given by the number of vectors in the basis. Therefore, $dim(W)=k \lt n$

Therefore, it has been shown that if $W \subseteq V$ then $dim(W) \le dim(V)$

Comment: Unfortunately, this attempt is pretty much nonsense. $\{\emptyset\}$ is probably not going to be a subspace or even a subset of $V$; I think you mean $\{0\}$, which has dimension zero. Also, I have no idea how you're going to study anything that's *not* the zero subspace. $$$$ For an approach that you might find useful: Any basis of $W$ can be extended to a basis of $V$.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is not a subspace. By definition subspaces have $0$ as an element. Also, supposing $k<n$ you are using the result thesis to prove it. Try use @user296602's hint.

Comment: Where did you define the set T?

Answer (score 8):

By way of contradiction, suppose that $W$ is a subspace of $V$, with $n = dim(W) > dim(V)$.

Let $\{v_{1}, .... , v_{n} \}$ be a basis for $W$. Then this is a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $W$. Since $W \subseteq V$, $\{v_{1}, .... , v_{n} \}$ is a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$ (*). This is a contradiction, since $n > dim(V)$.

To really complete this proof, I suggest you prove (*) yourself. Show that if a set $A$ is linearly independent in a subspace of $V$, then it is linearly independent in $V$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have  $m $ linearly independent vectors,  with $m\gt n $, in an  $n-$ dimensional space  (for the space would then have dimension  $\ge m $).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is correct but here is my attempt:
suppose $B_w$ is basis of $W$, $B_v$ basis of $V$.
Ignoring trivial cases of $W=0$ or $W=V$ we have: span$(B_w)\subset$span$(B_v)$ which implies for $x$ in span$(B_w)$, $x = \sum a_i\cdot b_{w_i}$ where $b_{w_i}\in B_w$

Then since $x\in$span$(B_v)$ automatically all elements of $B_w$ are in $B_v$ so $B_w\subset B_v$.